# Flash Cs5.5 - Saving/Loading to a mobile device

Tags: flash, mobile, file-handling

I am pretty fresh into working with mobile at all here but i am having no luck finding solid info on the basic principles of file saving/loading locally on a mobile device (specifically android).  Any help or links are super appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working in a game AIR iOS based and I saved the users scores in iPhone. To do this, I used the SharedObject of the flash lib and works great!
Take a look to this tutorial.

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

good lucky